Make an equation that could be true
Make an equation that could be true by moving just 1 matchstick.
Conditions:

You cannot change = to ≠.
You cannot invent your own notation. Notation must be well-known. For example, you cannot create your own definition of "=" that mean "A=B" is always true no matter what A and B are.



With bad enough keming, you can just move either of the horizontal sticks to the other side of the equals, creating two identical shapes.

This may be accepted as true

 

  The axiom of constructibility, written as V = L, is a possible axiom for set theory that asserts that every set is constructible.

 It is inconsistent with the proposition that zero sharp exists.



 Shift the slanted line on the right hand side a bit to the right:



 Explanation:  Regular 1 = Roman numeral 1 (italics)



 Move the vertical match on the RHS to the left of LHS to get$$II = 二$$where the LHS is the Roman 2 and the RHS is the Chinese 2.



 ${\huge{\it I} = {\it\Gamma\ I}}$

using the

 Gamma function

together with the

 no-parentheses-for-short-arguments convention.

This equation not only could be true; it is definitely true.

 Note: the capital "I"s in the formula are to be read as ones. I used them because they look matchstick-ier than actual ones.



 


 The LHS is empty [nothing], and the RHS is 0. The 0 can be considered as "nothing". 

 " " = "0"

